# pass info from Model to viewController without NSNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my viewController, I have a button that calls a method to start a timer in a Timer class. Just like this

main view controller

```
[self.timer startTimer];
```

In the timer class, `startTimer` calls a `countdownTime` method, both of which you can see below. Very simple. At the end of the countdownTime, method, the time is put in the label in the view like this as I iterate through a loop of the clocks.

```
 Timer *timerblah = self.gameClocks[i];
 [self.gameClocks[i] setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.time]];
```

In other words, the Timer class has an array property that holds all the clocks and that is connected to the view, hence the ability to set the text.

The problem with this code is that the model (i.e. Timer class) is setting the text in the view. I want the view Controller to get the time from the model and have the text set in the view controller i.e. have the viewController and only the viewController communicate with the view.  It is no problem for me to get the array of clocks in the viewController, however, I'm sure how to pass the time back from the countdownTime method to the viewController. It would seem like overkill to set up an NSNotification class to send the time back every second, wouldn't it?

```
 -(void)startTimer{
    self.NStimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(countdownTime:)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:YES];
}

-(void)countdownTime:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    #logic to countdown time
    self.minutes = self.secondsRemaining / 60;
    self.stringMinutes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.minutes];
    self.seconds = self.secondsRemaining - (self.minutes * 60);
    self.stringSeconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.seconds];

    if (self.seconds < 10) self.stringSeconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i", self.seconds];
    self.time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", self.stringMinutes, self.stringSeconds];
    self.secondsRemaining -= 1;
    if (self.secondsRemaining == 0){
        [self stopTimer];
    }

    #adding to the view (from the model i.e. in Timer.m class)
    for(int i = 0; i < [self.gameClocks count]; i++){
            Timer *timerblah = self.gameClocks[i];
            if (timerblah.systemClock == YES){
            [self.gameClocks[i] setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.time]];
            }
        }

}
```

Update

There's a comment suggesting that I use a block to do this. In the timer class, I added a method like this to return a string with the time (the time is set to self.time above)

```
-(NSString *)passTheTime:(NSString (^)(void))returnBlock

{
    return self.time;
}
```

I then, in view controller, call the method passTheTime on the timer class. I created a property in the view controller that will store the time, so I pass that as a parameter to the block,

```
 [self.timer passTheFoo:^NSString * (self.timeToSet){

        }];
```

a) I'm unsure of what to do in the block here.

b) I'm unsure of whether it was necessary to pass `self.timeToSet` into the block. How do I connect `self.time` from the Timer class to self.timeToSet in the view controller

c) there's an error `incompatible block pointer type sending NSString *((^)(void)) to parameter of type NSString(^)(void)`

d) alternatively, can I pass a block to startTimer, and have that block passed in the selector countdownTime and return the self.time once the calculations in countdownTime are finished?

Comment: maybe `delegate` will solve this ?

Comment: Use block method (callback method).

Create a method with black as argument in Timer class (model) and call it in view controller. This way once timer class method execution over, it will return back control to view controller class again with value you need from that method.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: @TechNet-Weblineindia thanks for the suggestion. I'm not very experienced with blocks and couldn't get it to work. could you glance at the update I did and make some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use block to update the label in the view controller class as below

In Timer Class, create a block

TimerClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


typedef void(^TimerCallback)(NSString *time); 

@interface TimerClass : NSObject{

    TimerCallback timerCallback;
    NSTimer     *timer;
}

- (void)startTimerWithCallBack:(TimerCallback)callback;

@end
```

In TimerClass.m , update the code as below

```
 #import "TimerClass.h"

    @implementation TimerClass


    - (void)startTimerWithCallBack:(TimerCallback)callback{

        timerCallback = callback;

        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(countdownTime:)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:YES];
    }


    -(void)countdownTime:(NSTimer *)timer
    {

        // countdown logic here

        // call the callback method with time as a parameter to the viewcontroller class

        // here for demo purpose I am passing random number as a value in callback, you need to pass the time that you want to display here
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1+arc4random()%10];

        timerCallback(str);

    }

    @end
```

In ViewController class, call the timer start method as follows

```
TimerClass *timer = [[TimerClass alloc] init];
    [timer startTimerWithCallBack:^(NSString *time) {
        lbl.text = time; // display time in label
    }];
```